# Saving and Closing Xlsx files

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2007, macros

Ok, I have created a `Xlsm` workbook that I need to deactivate some tabs and then I only need to save as a `Xlsx` to my desktop.  I don't need the file to open. I need to have the original `Xlsm` file to remain open so I can clear the data and enter different info and save that as well.  Can I do that with one macro? Here is what I have so far. It all works well except I have to close the `Xlsx` and reopen the `Xlsm` manually and when I do several dozens a day it gets tedious.

```
Sheets(Array("Contractor info", "PTW", "DataBase")).Select
Sheets("DataBase").Activate
ActiveWindow.SelectedSheets.Visible = False
ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:= _
    "C:\Users\U0154179\Desktop\ATW " & ActiveSheet.Range("B21").Value & "-" & ActiveSheet.Range("I3").Value & ".xlsx", FileFormat:= _
    xlOpenXMLWorkbook, CreateBackup:=False
ActiveWorkbook.Save
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Try something like:

```
Sub Macro3()
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
        ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:="C:\Users\garys\Desktop\arrr.xlsx", _
            FileFormat:=xlOpenXMLWorkbook, CreateBackup:=False
        ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:="C:\Users\garys\Desktop\arrr.xlsm", _
            FileFormat:=xlOpenXMLWorkbookMacroEnabled, CreateBackup:=False
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True
End Sub
```

Comment: What's wrong with the OP's current code? How will this achieve a different result than what the OP is already getting? A simple explanation would probably suffice.